# How to check well formedness of xml file which has encoding type of UTF-16 using Java?

Tags: java, xml

I have parsed an xml file which has encoding type UTF-8. It parses well.

I had nothing change any encoding type in the xml file.

***The xml header for UTF-8 looks like:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

There is no error for above format!!!

**Suppose i had another file to check well formedness which has header like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: What error? You haven't told us what error you're getting, or shown the code which is failing.

Comment: Are you sure that your UTF-16 has a proper BOM?

Comment: Could you please paste the XML? I use your code and works perfectly....

Answer (score 0):

Java xml parsers usually receive their input wrapped in an InputSource object. This can be constructed with a Reader parameter that does the character decoding for the given charset.

```
InputStream in = ...
InputSource is = new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(in, "utf-16"));
```

For the "utf-16" charset the stream should start with a byte order mark, if that is not the case use either "utf-16le" or "utf-16be".

Comment: i have used this format..but its not use, bcoz eventhough it shows same error.

can give some block of code to parse the xml file?

Comment: Why not let the XML parser do the validation itself, including detecting the encoding? Just pass it the stream, not a reader.

Comment: documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
               documentBuilderFactory.setValidating(false);
               documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
               documentBuilderFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
 DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
documentBuilder.setErrorHandler(new SimpleErrorHandler());
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(xmlFile);
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-16"));
documentBuilder.parse(inputSource);

Comment: the above code was i used , so the error comes as content not allowed in prolog

Comment: **The error i get:**
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 40; Content is not allowed in prolog.
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:254)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:300)

Comment: OK, so your XML file isn't well-formed and you are getting an error telling you it's not well formed. What more do you want?